# What is the extra argument used for when overloading the decrement operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, decrement, postfix-operator

When I overload the post-decrement operator, I have to include a extra argument:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class wrap
{
public:
    bool operator >(T &&v)
    {
        return value > v;
    }
    T operator --(int v) // Remove 'int v' and you get a compilation error
    {
        return (value -= 1) + 1;
    }
    wrap(T v)
    {
        value = v;
    }
private:
    T value;
};

int main(void)
{
    wrap<int> i(5);
    while(i --> 0)
        std::cout << "Why do we need the extra argument?\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove this seemingly unneeded argument, I get a compilation error:

> ```
> test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> test.cpp:26:13: error: no ‘operator--(int)’ declared for postfix ‘--’ [-fpermissive]
>      while(i --> 0)
>            ~~^~
> ```

What is this argument used for? What does its value represent?

Comment: An answer in the cited duplicate *does* explain that the `int` argument is a dummy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate but related overloads of `operator++` - [pre-increment and post-increment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec).  Both are overridable.  Since they both have the same name, the designers of C++ had to decide on a syntax to let the compiler differentiate between them.  They chose to use a dummy `int` parameter on the post-increment operator.

When you write code like this:

```cpp
wrap<int> i(5);
++i; // <-- calls i.operator++();
```

The compiler emits code to call the parameter-less `operator++()`.

When you write code like this instead:

```cpp
wrap<int> i(5);
i++; // <-- calls i.operator++(0);
```

The compiler emits code to call the parametered `operator++(int)`, passing `0` for the dummy parameter.

The *value* of the parameter is meaningless, its mere presence is enough to let each overload of `operator++` be overriden individually since they have different signatures.

BTW, the same rules apply to the pre/post-decrement `operator--` as well.

Comment: does this mean that a slight additional overhead is incurred by calling `my++` versus `++my`?

Comment: @PatrickParker yes, due to the extra parameter being pushed/popped on the call stack, and also because post-increment also returns a copy of the old value before it was incremented. Pre-increment returns a reference to the incremented value, not a copy

Answer (score 2):

Every ratified ANSI and ISO C++ standard, and every working draft, describes this, although the precise wording changes between versions.

For example, according to the "Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++", document number N4659, dated 2017-03-21, Section 16.5.7 "Increment and decrement [over.inc]", para 1

> The user-defined function called `operator++` implements the prefix and postfix `++` operator. If this function is a non-static member function with no parameters, or a non-member function with one parameter, it defines the prefix increment operator `++` for objects of that type. If the function is a non-static member function with one parameter (which shall be of type int) or a non-member function with two parameters (the second
>   of which shall be of type int), it defines the postfix increment operator `++` for objects of that type. When the postfix increment is called as a result of using the `++` operator, the int argument will have value zero.

At the end of the preceding para, there is a reference to footnote 134, which says

> Calling `operator++` explicitly, as in expressions like `a.operator++(2)`, has no special properties: The argument to `operator++` is `2`.

After para 1, the standard even provides an example.

> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     X& operator++(); // prefix ++a
>     X operator++(int); // postfix a++
> };
>
> struct Y { };
>   Y& operator++(Y&); // prefix ++b
>   Y operator++(Y&, int); // postfix b++
>
> void f(X a, Y b) {
>     ++a; // a.operator++();
>     a++; // a.operator++(0);
>     ++b; // operator++(b);
>     b++; // operator++(b, 0);
>
>     a.operator++(); // explicit call: like ++a;
>       a.operator++(0); // explicit call: like a++;
>       operator++(b); // explicit call: like ++b;
>       operator++(b, 0); // explicit call: like b++;
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Para 2 then goes on to say

> The prefix and postfix decrement operators `--` are handled analogously.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec):

> The `int` parameter is a dummy parameter used to differentiate between prefix and postfix versions of the operators. When the user-defined postfix operator is called, the value passed in that parameter is always zero, although it may be changed by calling the operator using function call notation (e.g., `a.operator++(2)` or `operator++(a, 2)`).

Though I would highly advise against making functionality around those explicit calls (as to anyone else it'll look extremely weird).

Comment: What does the ISO C++ standard say on this? I'm not using Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: @JL2210 C++ standard agrees--this is a core aspect of the language. I was just lazy and chose MS since they were high on the google list. I've edited to use cppreference though, which is probably a better source anyways.

Comment: Can I accept another answer? Some of the others go into slightly more detail.

Comment: @JL2 the system will let you unaccept mine and accept another if you feel another answer better answers your question/solves your problem. You don't need my permission! :)

Comment: OK. Just didn't want to make anybody mad.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using postfix decrement:

```
 while (i-- > 0)
```

which should decrement `i` but return the original value:

```
T operator--(int) // dummy int param for postfix
{
    T temp = value;
    value -= 1;
    return temp;
}
```

the dummy `int` parameter is just a placeholder to distinguish between postfix and the prefix decrement:

```
T operator--() // no param for prefix
{
    value -= 1;
    return value;
}
```